# UV Mapping - using Material from Shader editor

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

Does anyone have any hints on how to make sure one is using a predefined texture from the *Material Editor* when unwrapping meshes?

The only way I have been able to unwrap is by manually choosing picture, which however has none of the settings from my shading editor.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, could you explain a bit more what you mean? It looks like the object you have selected, as well as the one just to the right of it have the material applied. If you want the same material on all of them, select them all (in object mode), making sure one of the objects with the material already on it is the active one. Then press Ctrl+L and select "Link Materials"

Comment: Voting to reopen because the OP said that an answer solved the problem.